# how can I access frontend module from backend in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have created 'contact_us' CRUD in frontend. Now I want to show listing of that contact_us (i.e. index.php) in backend. how can I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a new urlMangerBackend in urlManager component  in your frontend application /config/main.php 
and then refer to this in your createUrl

```
return [
 ....
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        //  your normal frontend URL rules
    ],
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => '/yourapp/backend/web',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => true,
    ],

  ],
];
```

and you can invoke this way

```
 Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->createUrl();
```

Comment: @scaisEdge..Thank You.